# Flask: How to avoid generate any kind of answer for a specific URL

Tags: python, security, flask

I am programming a home Web server for home automation. I've seen several times 'bots' scanning the ports of my server. To avoid give any kind of activity signs to undesired scans, I'm trying to avoid generate any kind of answer for specific URLs, like '/', ie. configure a silent mode for the typical scanned URL's. 
I've tried with void .route decorators, error addressing and void pages, but all of them generated some kind of response.
It's that possible in Flask with Python?
Any workaround?
Thanks

Comment: is '/' a valid url for which certain IPs should receive a valid response? also somewhat tangential to this, you should consider running fail2ban on your server if you are worried about bots scanning your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to return a custom error code for urls you are getting scanned, like HTTP_410_GONE.

> From: http://www.flaskapi.org/api-guide/status-codes/

```
@app.route('/')
def empty_view(self):
    content = {'please move along': 'nothing to see here'}
    return content, status.HTTP_410_GONE
```

Put nginx in front of your flask app and use a fail2ban config to watch for this error code and start banning ips that are constantly hitting these urls.

> From: https://github.com/mikechau/fail2ban-configs/blob/master/filter.d/nginx-404.conf

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST> - - \[.*\] "(GET|POST).*HTTP.* 410
ignoreregex =
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same need as you and decided to just `return` from `404` and `500` handlers:

```
    @staticmethod
    @bottle.error(404)
    def error404(error):
        log.warning("404 Not Found from {0} @ {1}".format(bottle.request.remote_addr, bottle.request.url))

    @staticmethod
    @bottle.error(500)
    def error500(error):
        log.warning("500 Internal Error from {0} @ {1}".format(bottle.request.remote_addr, bottle.request.url))
```

The example is for `bottle` but you can adapt it with `flask`.

Beside catching the obvious `404` I decided to do the same with `500` in case an unexpected call from the scanners would crash my script so that no traceback information is provided.